# Protecting iMacs from high humidity

Tags: imac, performance

I am moving to Costa Rica and want to take both of my iMacs.  Humidity and salt air are a problem.  Will leaving the iMac running help to keep humidity out of the unit?  I see only one vent;  maybe a cover?

Comment: Note: do not cover the vent. Different iMacs have different designs. Which iMac models do you own?

Answer (score 3):

Humidity is not an issue.

Humid air on a warm/hot computer components won't be a problem.  It's when the temperature of the components are lower than the [dew point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dew_point) of the ambient air that it will become a concern; water will condense.

Running the computer won't keep humid air out as it's the ambient air that gets circulated.  Unless your computer somehow gets colder than the room that it's located in, it will be fine.

(I live in the tropics with many, many 100% humidity days)

Comment: Well you've either been really lucky or I've had horrible luck. 9 macbooks in 10 years, CR & Belize coasts